# Is it possible to send the html output from a blade template through a JSON?

Tags: laravel-4

In an application I am loading the pages through AJAX calls (instead of the regular browser loading) so I'm wondering if it's possible to add the output from a blade template in a JSON return?

I designed my application around a JSON looking like this:

```
return Response::json(array('id' => "1",'urlString' => "admin/posts", 'html' => "<p>test</p>"),200);
```

I need the HTML index in the JSON to be the output from a blade template, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible by calling the `render()` method of the view :

```
  $view = View::make('some.view');
  $view->somevariable = 'some value';
  $html = $view->render();

  return Response::json(array('id' => "1",'urlString' => "admin/posts", 'html' => $html);
```